# Estou fazendo um exercício em Go e algo não está funcionando no código

Tags: lógica, golang

sou estudante ainda e tenho tentado praticar em Golang com alguns exercícios de lógica de programação.

O programa basicamente consiste em fazer o seguinte:

Exemplo

```
Dados da primeira pessoa:
Nome: Maria Silva
Idade: 19
Dados da segunda pessoa:
Nome: Joao Melo
Idade 20
A idade média de Maria Silva e Joao Melo é de 19.5 anos
```

O meu código ficou assim:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var nome1 int
    var nome2 int
    var idade1, idade2 int
    var media float32
    fmt.Println("Dados da primeira pessoa:")
    fmt.Print("Nome: ")
    fmt.Scan(&nome1)
    fmt.Print("Idade: ")
    fmt.Scan(&idade1)
    fmt.Println("Dados da segunda pessoa:")
    fmt.Print("Nome: ")
    fmt.Scan(&nome2)
    fmt.Print("Idade: ")
    fmt.Scan(&idade2)

    media = float32((idade1 + idade2) / 2)
    fmt.Printf("\nA idade média de %d e %d é de %f anos", &nome1, &nome2, &media)
```

Eu tentei algumas variações, tentar converter, mas o que acontece com o código acima é essa saída aqui:

```
Dados da primeira pessoa:
Nome: Maria
Idade: Dados da segunda pessoa:
Nome: Idade:
A idade média de 824633819272 e 824633819296 é de %!f(*float32=0xc0000180b8) anos
PS C:\Users\alexi\Meu Drive\Programação\golang>
```

Ou seja, o programa não pergunta de um em um. Eu respondo o nome da pessoa (Maria) e ele ao invés de perguntar o nome da segunda pessoa, já manda tudo junto.

Eu já tentei de tudo e não consigo entender o que deu errado. Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda? Agradeço demais!

Answer (score -3):

Identifiquei 2 problemas na sua implementação.

O primeiro deles é a maneira que você *tipou* as variáveis `nome1` e `nome2`. Ambas deveriam ser do tipo `string`, no código fornecido, elas foram declaradas como `int`. Corrigindo isso, seu programa não terá mais problemas com a leitura de strings **não espaçadas**. Entretanto, como no seu caso os dados fornecidos são compostos por nome e sobrenome, ou seja, uma `string` que obrigatoriamente possui um espaço vazio, foi necessário criar um sistema de extração personalizado, já que a função `fmt.Scan` não consegue lidar com a formatação exigida. Para isso o método `bufio.NewReader` foi utilizado.

Outro problema que reparei no seu fonte, é no *print* final da execução. Lá, você deve substituir os parâmetros `&nome1, &nome2` por `nome1, nome2`, dessa maneira o programa irá imprimir os valores das variáveis, não seus endereços.

Segue o fonte com as correções aplicadas:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var nome1, nome2 string
    var idade1, idade2 float64

    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Println("Dados da primeira pessoa:")
    fmt.Print("Nome: ")
    nome1, _ = r.ReadString('\n')
    nome1 = strings.TrimSuffix(nome1, "\n")
    fmt.Print("Idade: ")
    fmt.Scan(&idade1)

    fmt.Println("Dados da segunda pessoa:")
    fmt.Print("Nome: ")
    nome2, _ = r.ReadString('\n')
    nome2 = strings.TrimSuffix(nome2, "\n")
    fmt.Print("Idade: ")
    fmt.Scan(&idade2)

    media := (idade1 + idade2) / 2
    fmt.Printf("A idade média de %s e %s é de %f anos\n", nome1, nome2, media)
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Vinícius! Me ajudou demais